# Push Mysql Result to Array in Node Js

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am trying to push the result of an sql query to an array but keep getting an empty array. Am not sure if am using the async and await properly.

Here is the code

```
    exports.get_all_post = async(req, res, next) => {
        
        let search_list = [];
        const result = await query("SELECT * FROM post");
        result.forEach(async row =>{
            //console.log(row);
            const post_category_id = row.post_category_id;
            const post_id = row.post_id;
            try{
                const result2 = await query("SELECT * FROM post_category WHERE id = ?", post_category_id);
    
                const category_name = result2[0].name.toLowerCase();
                //console.log(category_name);
    
                const values = [category_name, post_id];
                const result3 = await query("SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE id = ?", values);
                search_list.push(result3[0]);
            } catch(error){
               console.log(error)
            }
        })
        console.log(search_list);
    
    
    }
```

I want the result push to the search list array but instead am getting an empty []

Comment: Is `category_name` your table name?

Comment: **Yes it is the name of the table**

Comment: When i change **search_list.push(result3[0]);**  to **console.log(result3[0]);**, I get a result in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You should await them in promises.

```
const promises = // result.forEach...

await Promise.all(promises);
console.log(search_list);
```

Comment: I got this after trying what you said

(node:9276) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined
    at Function.all (<anonymous>)
    at exports.get_all_post (C:\Uspost.ts:27:19)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:9276) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().

Comment: I think one of your promises is rejecting. Please try and catch the promises while you await them all.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone encounter the same challenge. Here is how i fixed it.

```
exports.get_all_post = async(req, res, next) => {
    
    let search_list = [];
    const result = await query("SELECT * FROM post");
    result.forEach(async row =>{
        //console.log(row);
        const post_category_id = row.post_category_id;
        const post_id = row.post_id;
        try{
            const result2 = await query("SELECT * FROM post_category WHERE id = ?", post_category_id);

            const category_name = result2[0].name.toLowerCase();
            //console.log(category_name);

            const values = [category_name, post_id];
            const result3 = await query("SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE id = ?", values);
            search_list.push(result3[0]);
            if(search_list.length == result.length){
                console.log(search_list);
            }
        } catch(error){
           console.log(error)
        }
    })
}
```